# Network interface doesn't start on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nic

Can't connect to my VM on GCP. Everything was OK before I stopped it and turned on again. Here's below syslog1  from GCP console from machine that I can't connect to.

[image]

Here's below syslog2 from newly created machine, with network interfaces started normally.
[image]

Comment: Your syslog does not indicate an error. Are you connecting to the correct TCP/IP `external` address?

Comment: Yes, I tried to connect to the machine directly from GCP console ssh.

Comment: When you connect using GCP console SSH, what error are you receiving? However, use the CLI `gcloud` to connect via SSH so that you get more detailed error messages. Note: If you are going to include screenshots of errors, make sure that they have errors. Your have no errors related to SSH or networking. Instead your screenshot show that networking is working.

Comment: UPD. Finally I am able to connect to my machine. But there is no log from unsuccessful boot, that is on first screenshot. In syslog file there are logs from first boot, when the VM was created and the third one, when I connected to VM. But there is no log from second boot, when I wasn't able to connect to the VM, though the status of the VM was 'running' at that time.

Comment: You should always install StackDriver so that logs are not lost, deleted, etc.

Comment: It seems that VM didn't start at all, so logs, that are on screenshot, couldn't get to syslog file. Same issue reproduced on another VM, so I connected to it through serial port and entered Ctrl+D command, and boot up successfully proceeded. I suppose that something is blocking boot up process. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have followed the help center article about [general troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#troubleshooting_general_issues_with_instances) steps. As explained there, please verify that your disk has a valid file system. If the steps mentioned there doesn't work for you, detaching the persistent disk and [use that disk on a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#use_your_disk_on_a_new_instance) would be next best option.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but everything's OK with file system. The problem is that machines don't start after being stopped for the first time, and successfully boot up only after restart. For example, I create a new VM, stop it and when I try to start it, boot up process freezes at the moment, which you can see on the first screenshot, and it starts normally only if I restart it. This issue reproduced several times and it happened to boot up successfully after more than one reboot. When it freezes at that moment, sometimes Ctrl+D helped and boot up process continued.

Comment: What image and version is the affected VM instance created in? so that I can try to reproduce here since is happening on every instance upon reboot.